# How to retrieve data of CKEditor in code behind of an aspx page

Tags: ckeditor, code-behind, data-retrieval

I'm trying to integrate CKEditor with my application and I'm using the below approach.

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

and in JavaScript to set and get data to ckeditor I'm using the code as below

```
function cksetdata(val)
        {
           CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(val);
       }
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

It is working perfect when using JavaScript.

but I want to set and get data from code behind as I want to save the data of CKEditor into database.

If using the CKEditor as control in aspx page I'm able to retrieve data by using `.Text` property of CKEditor, but unable to get data through JavaScript.

I need to retrieve data from both JavaScript and codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for ur answer Mr.Raymond kuipers..

Im using a work around for this problem..

As im able to retrieve data in javascript im assigning that data to a hidden variable and accessing the value of that hidden variable in my button save event..

```
    function getCkEditordata() {
    document.getElementById('<%=hdn1.ClientID%>').value = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    alert(document.getElementById('<%=hdn1.ClientID%>').value);
}
```

in this way assigning to a hidden variable and accessing that data in code behind as follows..

```
String templatecontent =  hdn1.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the CKEeditorForAspNet nuget package and you will have a normal control in aspx. You can than set and get the data using the .Text property.

Comment: yes.. u r absolutely right . While using as a control i can get data using the .Text property. But im unable to get and set data through javascript. I need to retrieve data from both javascript and code behind.